# Snakemake: exporting d3dag - MissingInputException

Tags: snakemake

I want to export the DAG of my workflow in D3.js compatible JSON format:

```
snakemake.snakemake(snakefile=smfile,
                    dryrun=True,
                    forceall=True,
                    printdag=False,
                    printd3dag=True,
                    keepgoing=True,
                    cluster_config=cluster_config,
                    configfile=configfile,
                    targets=targetfiles)
```

Unfortunately, it complains about missing input files.

It is right about the fact that the files are missing but I had hoped that it would run anyways, especially after setting the `keepgoing` option to `True`.

Is there a way to export the DAG without the input files?

Answer (score 0):

`--keep-going` allows [execution of independent jobs if a snakemake job fails](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executable.html#EXECUTION). That is, snakemake has to successfully start running jobs. In your case, it never gets to that stage. I would imagine missing input files would not allow creation of DAG.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I chose a workaround that parses the error messages from snakemake and creates dummy input files. This runs in a loop until no `MissingInputException` occurs any more.